# Python Selenium Webdriver Wait.Until is showing error takes exactly 2 arguments 3 given

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Webdriver.  I am having trouble clicking on an Add button.
I am using Webdriver Wait, I am getting the following error when i run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 164, in test_add_Project
administration_page.add_project(project_name)
File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Pages\admin.py", line 63, in add_project
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), "Projects")]/following-sibling::*/div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), "Add...")]'))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

My webdriver code is

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), "Projects")]/following-sibling::*/div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), "Add...")]'))
element.click()
```

What am i doing wrong?
The Xpath is valid as i have checked it in Firefox, Firepath.  It finds the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enclose the locator in a tuple:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel" and contains(text(), "Projects")]/following-sibling::*/div[@class="gwt-HTML" and contains(text(), "Add...")]')))
```

Comment: I am getting a Timeout Exception.  If i put it in a Try Catch block will that help?

Comment: @RiazLadhani well, at least we've proceeded to a different problem. This can be that there is a problem with locator, or the element is really not getting clickable..you can catch the timeout exception, yes, but didn't you want to get that element and click it?..